# Multiple Screen Sizes Adobe Air for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm building my game with Adobe Air for iOS but I'm also building the game for Android.Because my main platform is iOS, the dimensions are set to 960x640, but when I put the game onto a different device such as my Nexus there is white all around the screen.I know this might be meant to happen, but when my friend does the exact same thing (screen size is the same also) and runs it on his Nexus, it fits the screen.I was just wondering if there is anyway that this can be enabled/disabled.

Plus: I do have white rectangles around the screen, could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following link, this might be useful for you :

[Supporting multiple screen sizes](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html)